# How can I keep my other attributes stationary when I sticky a navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been developing a project for awhile in which I've created a navbar that is `static` until scrolled to, at which point it becomes `fixed` to the top of the screen. This navbar works well, but when it stickies, the elements beneath it jump upwards to fill the void it left. How can I make it so these elements remain stationary once the navbar's `position` changes? I've included the relevant code below, in case it's needed.

HTML:

```
<div id="navbar"><ul>
    <li id="activePage"><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Upcoming events </a><li>
    <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contribute</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

css:

```
#navbar {
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1;
}

#navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#navbar li {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
}

#navbar ul #activePage a {
    color: #cec8c8;
}

#navbar li a {
    color: black;
    padding: 14px 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var elementPosition = $('#navbar').offset();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top) {
            $('#navbar').css('position', 'fixed').css({'top':'0','left':'0','right':'0');
        } else {
            $('#navbar').css('position', 'static');
}})});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, as you already hinted at, is as soon as you change the navbar position to fixed, you're removing it from the page flow and the rest of the page content underneath is sent "upwards" to fill the void.

If you have a div already wrapping the page content below the navbar, add this within your if statement and it will add the margin at the same time your navbar is removed from the flow of the page.

```
 // Added margin top to the content's wrapper to account for the navbar being taken out of the flow of the page.
 $('***Main Content Wrapper Class/ID***').css('margin-top', '***[[THE HEIGHT OF THE NAV]]***'); 
// Once your scroll top is back to where the navbar is static again
  $('***Main Content Wrapper Class/ID***').css('margin-top', '0');
```

---

OR

---

```
// Or you can add a class and remove a class with the margin-top style within
   $('Main Content Wrapper Class/ID').addClass('scrolledNav');


   // Once your scroll top is back to where the navbar is static again
      $('Main Content Wrapper Class/ID').removeClass('scrolledNav');
```

**CSS:**

```
  .scrolledNav {
        margin-top: [navbar height]px
    }
```